# Hibenrate exception: identifier of an instance of X was altered when trying to merge object

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm writing a Spring application. In my application I have a rest API that updates a Shop object. The Shop object has a reference to a default currency object. My rest client sends post request with the following JSON payload.

```
{ 
currency: {id: "EUR", name: "Euro", symbol: "€"},
description : "Bla bla bla"
id : "SHOP-00006"
isActive : null
location : "the moon"
name : "Delicious Foo"
numberOfProducts : 0
profilePicture : null
}
```

My service looks like this:

```
@Transactional
public List<ShopData> updateShop(User user, ShopData shopData) {
  Shop shop = shopRepository.getById(shopData.getId());
  mapper.map(shopData, shop);
  entityManager.merge(shop);
  return getUserShops(user);
}
```

Where ShopData is a DTO that holds the data received from the user. And mapper.map copies the DTO to the domain object.

This method throws the following exception:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of
>   com.companyname.application.domain.common.Currency was altered from USD to
>   EUR   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:80)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:192)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:152)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:61)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1227)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1293)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)

Finally the relevant domain classes are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop")
public class Shop extends AnEntity {

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    protected String name;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    protected String description;

    @Column(name = "location")
    protected String location;

    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected User owner;

    @JoinColumn(name = "currency_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected Currency currency;

    @Column(name = "profile_picture")
    protected String profilePicture;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    protected Boolean isActive;
// getters and setters
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "currency")
public class Currency extends AnEntity {

    @Column(name = "name", length = 124)
    protected String name;

    @Column(name = "symbol", length = 3)
    protected String symbol;
    // setters and getters
}
```

It seems like hibernate is trying to merge my currency object even though I haven't specified any cascade value on the relation. Why does hibernate try to do that, instead of changing the currency reference to the new one? And how should this be done, if I'm making a mistake in my code?

(EDIT)

My table structure as follows:

[image: currency]
[image: shop]

Comment: I guess in this entity is not getting detached from the session previously created by any other method. You have to detach User Entity Correctly.

Comment: can you show your table structure of shop and currency?

Comment: @shankarsh15 do you mean the Currency entity? How do I do that?

Comment: @Vijay I added the tables structure to the question, although I don't see how this could be related to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved this issue.

```
@Transactional
public List<ShopData> updateShop(User user, ShopData shopData) {
  Shop updateShop = mapper.map(shopData, Shop.class);
  entityManager.merge(updatedShop);
  return getUserShops(user);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are changing the `ID` of an entity, which you should not be doing. If you are referring to your currency instance using a managed entity, you should be replacing the whole entity instead. Hibernate cannot manage to guess why the `ID` property of an object changed which I believe is not allowed.

Here I see 2 options:

- in your mapper reload the `currency` entity you set in your `shop` instance and re-set it using a setter instead of mapping from JSON
- use a different type of reference to your currency, e.g. only the `ID` field instead of actual object reference

If you don't want your `Currency` to be persisted, add a `CascadeType` to the declaration:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "currency_id")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
protected Currency currency;
```

Comment: what you say makes sense, albeit it doesn't resolve the exception. Based on what you said, I thought the mapper is mapping the currency property of shopData to shop and copying its values, including the id to the old currency object. But why does hibernate try to persist the currency object?
I added the following two lines to updateShop
        `Currency currency = entityManager.find(Currency.class, shopData.getId());`
        `shop.setCurrency(currency);`
After the map call but still get the same exception. Also tried `shop.setCurrency(null);` in the mapper to no avail.

Comment: if you don't want your currency to be persisted, add a `CascadeType` to the reference

Comment: Creating a new Shop object fixed it. 
`Shop updateShop = mapper.map(shopData, Shop.class);`
 `entityManager.merge(updateShop);` Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I see that you are reusing the shop object and hence the second call to this method will try to update the shop object created by the first call.

```
public List<ShopData> updateShop(User user, ShopData shopData) {
    mapper.map(shopData, shop);
```

Create a new local Shop object and use that in your map method.

Comment: I had missed a line from the updateShop method earlier. I added it now. I'm getting a Shop object and mapping the user ShopData object to it, then merging it. Is this wrong?

Comment: with your updated code, I don't see the shop object as a problem.  Do you have the variable for id column in Currency?  I cant see that from your OP.

Comment: Shop and Currency inherit their id's from AnEntity.